# Setup a classroom Linux system

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I need to set up a 30-user Ubuntu classroom. All our PCs are currently Microsoft Windows based and run from Windows servers. In the school I need my students to have full access to Ubuntu OS, so that they can learn how to use Linux, with ability to run sudo etc.

I've been looking at a few ways of sorting this out. Initially I thought I would install VirtualBox on all of the PC's (on individual images), but this would mean the students would always have to use the same computer, so this isn't ideal.

Now I am trying to think of a way for the client machines to use VirtualBox and connect using their own username and password to a 'Server'.

Does anybody have any recommendations for setting this up? Is there a way I can set up a VirtualBox of Ubuntu, and have different users connect to it as if it was their own machine?

I would need to be able to see all of the users files and they need to be able to save onto their own Ubuntu desktop.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand the detail of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I'm afraid this question is really too broad to be on topic here. If you [edit] it and make it more specific, we might be able to help. Do some background reading, get a general idea of what you need and ask specific questions about the various goals you will need to reach on the way.

Comment: @terdon - I'm sorry, hopefully now I have added a bit more information. I am really looking for a general idea of how to set up a small Ubuntu networks using one server and 30 virtual boxes. I have some experience in Linux, but not much in terms of setting up a network that could run from one machine! Thanks

Comment: OK, that's better, thanks. You also need to explain what OS the server will be running, whether you would be willing to use a Linux server, what level of permissions you want to give your students, whether you want their data to be persistent or disappear on reboot etc.

Comment: It'd need to be something simple. I could run a server, although would this take a lot of work to set up? 

Yes, it would be good if they can use the GUI. Data should appear when they log in. They need root access to their own machine.

Answer (score 0):

I will setup as this
Use a windows machine(we call it,windows KVM in this example)
and put it virtualbox or vmware(i prefer virtualbox,more fast)
In this server put 30 vm(remind to setup ram,disk space,etc) with ubuntu
,you can start from a one virgin machine and then clone it to 30 other clones.
On each pc windows,install putty and configure it for reach the vm's of windows KVM,so the users can learn linux and can also broke the VM,you will recover fast cloning again a virtualmachine on KVM.